# If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are subsets of $S$, then $E_1 \cap (E_2 \cap{E_1}^C) = \varnothing $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are subsets of $S$, then $E_1$ and $E_2 \cap \overline{E_1}$ are mutually exclusive, where $\overline{E_1}$ is the complement of $E_1$.

Is there a way to prove this without drawing a Venn Diagram, e.g. using propositional logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that $\;E_1\;$ and $\;E_2 \cap \overline{E_1}\;$ are mutually exclusive, i.e., that
$$
(0) \;\;\; E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \overline{E_1} = \emptyset
$$
So let's just calculate which elements are in the set on the left hand side: for any $\;x \in S\;$,
\begin{align}
& x \in E_1 \cap E_2 \cap \overline{E_1} \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$, twice"} \\
& x \in E_1 \land x \in E_2 \land x \in \overline{E_1} \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\overline{\phantom{E_1}}\;$"} \\
& x \in E_1 \land x \in E_2 \land \lnot(x \in E_1) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"the first and third parts contradict each other"} \\
& \text{false} \\
\end{align}
This proves $(0)$, and that completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$E_1 \cap (E_2 \cap \overline{E_1}) = E_2 \cap (E_1 \cap \overline{E_1}) = E_2 \cap \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

with out using Venn diagram :

Do you see that $E_1$ and $\bar{E_1}$ are mutually disjoint???

Now, as $E_2\cap \bar{E_1}$ is a subset of $\bar{E_1}$

one should immediately be able to see that $E_1$ and $E_2\cap \bar{E_1}$

what we have used here is  :

For two sets $A,B$

If $A$ does not intersect with $B$ then $A$ would not interrsect a subset of $B$..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- $E_1$ and $\overline{E_1}$ are disjoint.
- Given $A \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ and $B \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, if $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint, then $A$ and $B$ are disjoint as well.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$